# Gzip files are corrupted when downloaded off an Apache 2.4.28 server. Fine via FTP/SZ

Tags: apache, gzip

I am not sure when this started happening, but I have noticed that when I download .gz (gzip) files through httpd (apache 2.4.28), and try to open them on the client they are corrupted.

If I download them via sz, ftp, or another method they open fine on the client. If I transfer them via scp to another server and download them they work fine.

At first I thought it could be mod_deflate compressing it more than it should and corrupting it, but I disabled mod_deflate and the behavior still occurs.

I then downloaded nginx-1.12.2.tar.gz from nginx.org using wget on the server. When I downloaded that through Apache, it opened fine on the client.

As another test, I created a gz file on another server and transfered it over to the problematic one. Tried downloading that & it was corrupted.

So not really sure whats going on here. Can't seem to get a rhyme or reason to this bug.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an incorrect mime type in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: What *incorrect mime type*? Can you expand your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with apache 2.2 and 2.4, but removing

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

from the vhosts configuration file (and doing an apache reload) fixed it for me on either machine.

Make sure to restart or at least reload apache after changing the vhosts config.